# Mobile Menu: First click "opens" dropdown, Second click goes to actual link

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap 3 but for desktop I need to override the no parent click for dropdown menus, so I have done that with this code:

```
$('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function(){
    location.href = this.href;
});
```

However, on mobile I need my parent links to open the subnav on first click, then go to the actual link on second click.

Here is the dev site: http://bauer-dev.windmilldesignworks.com/, so for example, Products currently opens the subnav on first click, which is correct, but when its open (second click) I need it to actually take you to the products page.

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

Many touchscreen-only browsers activate CSS hover effects on the first tap, and only follow the link (and trigger a click event) on the second tap.  You'll want to disable the :hover styles on mobile.